# Cannot resolve symbol 'AuthUI'

Tags: java, android

I am adding firebase google and Gmail sign in but when I pasted my code in 
onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) method i got this error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'AuthUI'

on AuthUI word and all AuthUI words got red in 
onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) method.

**Code of MainActivity**

```
package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN=1;

    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;

    private String mUsername;

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference databaserefrence;
    private ChildEventListener databaselistener;

   private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener auhtlistener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaserefrence= database.getReference().child("messages");

        auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Initialize references to views
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
        List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, friendlyMessages);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
        mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
            }
        });

        // Enable Send button when there's text to send
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Send messages on click
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);
                databaserefrence.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                // Clear input box
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

        databaselistener= new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
            {
                mMessageAdapter.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        databaserefrence.addChildEventListener(databaselistener);

        auhtlistener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth)
            {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if(user!=null)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setAvailableProviders(
                                            Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.TWITTER_PROVIDER).build()))
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };
        auth.addAuthStateListener(auhtlistener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Code of FriendlyMessage.java**

```
package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

public class FriendlyMessage {

    private String text;
    private String name;
    private String photoUrl;

    public FriendlyMessage()
    {

    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
}
```

**Code for message adapter class**

```
package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendlyMessage> {
    public MessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FriendlyMessage> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        TextView authorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

        FriendlyMessage message = getItem(position);

        boolean isPhoto = message.getPhotoUrl() != null;
        if (isPhoto) {
            messageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
                    .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
                    .into(photoImageView);
        } else {
            messageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            photoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messageTextView.setText(message.getText());
        }
        authorTextView.setText(message.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Code of build.gradle(project:friendlyChat)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' //alrae

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' //already
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Code for build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Displaying images
    // already
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You should add this dependency.
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'

Comment: @Umair. In general mark the correct answer since it can help other users. Here some link about stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
 2.3.0               11.0.4
```

You should add this in your `build.gradle` section .

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is confusing but you have to implement 2 firebase library for using UI.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in your build.gradle section .

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.6.1'
```

Comment: this worked fine for me on android-studio-ide-173.4819257-linux.

Answer (score 0):

**Only need to add below line on build.gradle**

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'

Comment: Welcome to SO, nice to have you here :) Small hint: Try to avoid posting duplicate answers.